# $PATH variable is messed up, where is it being sourced from in Mac Catalina

Tags: bash, terminal, .bash-profile, profile

When I echo $PATH in terminal, I see a big string that kind of looks messed and has some old irrelevant paths. I would like to fix this. But first, I'd like to understand when I echo $PATH in terminal, in mac os catalina, where is that variable being sourced from?

The only exports I am aware of currently are in `~/.zshrc` and some of the commands in the $PATH variable aren't in there.

Note, I don't have a `.profile` and `.bash_profile`.

I appreciate any clarification

Comment: Look into `/etc/environment`, if you have one

Answer (score 1):

Before exec'ing your shell, the system sets up the PATH environment variable from entries in the file `/etc/paths` and any files in the directory `/etc/paths.d`. Then, as you know, once it exec's your shell, depending on your shell and how it was invoked, your shell probably sources some shell startup scripts some of which may be system wide like `/etc/profile`, and some specific to your user account, like `~/.profile`.

To learn the specifics of how your shell chooses shell startup scripts to source, check the man page (or other documentation) for your shell.